# Blazor component derived from InputBase<decimal> compiler complains about converting decimal to string, then complains about left hand of assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to create a custom input component that wraps some Bootstrap around the input. Got it working fine for string fields, however, with a decimal field, can't get it working. My code:

RecipientDto:

```
public class RecipientDto
{
            
   [Range(1, 2)]
   public decimal Wtf { get; set; }

   //other props removed
}
```

Inherited from InputBase:

```
@inherits InputBase<decimal>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="@id">@Label</label>
    <input @bind="CurrentValue" class="form-control @CssClass" id="@id" />
    <div class="form-control-validation">
        @if (ValidationFor != null)
        {
            <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> ValidationFor { get; set; }

    protected string id { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)) id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out decimal result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal parsed);

        result = parsed;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<EditForm Model="currRecipient">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    @*<FGNumber_Mt Label="Wtf, over" @bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf" />*@

    <FGNumber_Mt Label="Wtf, over" @bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()" />

</EditForm>
```

The compiler compains that it can't convert from decimal to string with `<FGNumber_Mt Label="Wtf, over" @bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf" />` .

However, when I add the `.ToString()` on the `@bind-value`, i.e. `<FGNumber_Mt Label="Wtf, over" @bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()" />`, it complains:

[image]

Ideally I'd like to not have to call `.ToString()`, but either way, what am I doing wrong here?

Also, in case it matters, I want to be able to do the same with all primitive types. Doing a bootstrap checkbox is annoying enough in an MVC app with Intellisense helping out, but yeesh, gotta be a better way to skin that cat than having to do such repetitive keyboard key presses.

P.S. A heartfelt thank you to everyone who spends time answering questions on here. I've learned tons from SO. Head bowed.

Comment: What does your ```FGNumber_Mt``` ```Value``` parameter look like? Is it decimal or string?

Comment: For the string to decimal error, did you try adding `type="number"` to your input?

Comment: @DouglasRiddle It's in the `RecipientDto` class, a decimal

Comment: @ConnorLow That would only get passed in as an `AdditionalAttributes` thingy, and would have no effect on what the compiler is seeing.

Comment: @DouglasRiddle Did you mean the `CurrentValue` on the `InputBase<decimal>` derived component? That's also a decimal.

Comment: Right, I'm thinking of Svelte :). `InputNumber` would be the way to go, but that might not work in your case.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida, no I meant ```Value```, but I missed that your "Inherited from InputBase" code block was the ```FGNumber_Mt``` component. I copied your example code into a temporary project and it compiled and ran as expected.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe that `@bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf"` shouldn't give any errors. As the type of `Value` parameter of `InputBase<decimal>` is `decimal` and there is no need to convert `.Wtf` that is also a `decimal` to `string` in order for the binding to work. I copied your code and it works without any errors. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Regarding the errors you see when you do `@bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()"`, you need to understand what two-way bindings (`@bind-` syntax) do under the hood. There is no magic happening here, doing:

`<FGNumber_Mt @bind-Value="currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()" />`

is conceptually equivalent to doing:

`<FGNumber_Mt Value="currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()" ValueChanged="@(value => currRecipient.Wtf.ToString() = value)" />`

That being so the errors are now more clear.

- The first error you see complains about this part `currRecipient.Wtf.ToString() = value`. Of course you can't do this even in plain C#, `currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()` cannot be the left-hand side of an assignment.
- The second error complains about assigning `currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()` to `Value` parameter. The expression (`currRecipient.Wtf.ToString()`) returns a string but the parameter requires a `decimal` value. You can't assign a `string` value to a `decimal` parameter.

Bonus tip:
You don't need the intermediate `parsed` variable in your `TryParseValueFromString` method. You can simply pass the `result` parameter to `decimal.TryParse` as an out argument.

```
protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out decimal result, out string validationErrorMessage)
{
    decimal.TryParse(value, out result);

    validationErrorMessage = null;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know. Gave up yesterday, shut down VS, when I opened it just now, no compiler errors, works fine. Thanks for the tip about parsed.